# Which JavaScript files from node_modules gets transferred from server to browser in MERN application

Tags: reactjs, node-modules, mern

I am new to MERN stack and creating one application, and trying to understand few things, my MERN application is having many packages which in-turn is nothing but JavaScript files. So my questions are

1. Does any of the JavaScript files from package folder (i.e. node_modules) gets transferred to from server to browser
2. If Yes, then what is the trigger point of transferring any JavaScript file from server at node_module to the browser.
3. My MERN application is having many React component, which is nothing but a JavaScript files. So which JavaScript file gets transferred from server to the browser

Answer (score 0):

Trying to answer to the best of my ability here:

1. As far as my knowledge goes, JavaScript is powerful enough to be used for building a full stack application, complete with front end, back end, and middleware.
2. Node Modules folder is needed to run the application locally, i.e., when using 'npm start'. I'm guessing this is where the server to browser transfer occurs.
3. React is a component-building library. It's used to create reusable components which get displayed in the browser.